How to Dynamically Update Telegram Chats Subscribed by a Telethon Userbot Without Restarting?
I am using a Telethon userbot to monitor messages across all chats (groups, channels, etc.) that an account is subscribed to. However, I have encountered two problems:

New chats are not tracked after subscription: If I subscribe to a new chat (group or channel) while the script is running, I do not receive any events or messages from that chat until I restart the script.
Old chats are still tracked after unsubscribing: If I leave a chat while the script is running, I still receive events and messages from that chat until the script is restarted.

Restarting the script resolves both issues, but I want to handle this dynamically without needing a manual restart. How can I achieve this?
Here’s the relevant part of my script:
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.events import NewMessage
from telethon.types import UpdateNewMessage

user_bot = TelegramClient(
   session=phone,
   api_id=api_id,
   api_hash=api_hash,
   system_version = "4.16.30-vxCUSTOM",
   device_model = "iPhone 11"
)

@user_bot.on(NewMessage(incoming=True))
async def new_message(event: UpdateNewMessage):
    # Process incoming messages
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    while True:
        try:
            user_bot.start(phone=phone)
            user_bot.run_until_disconnected()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error: {e}")

How can I ensure that:

New subscriptions are dynamically tracked without restarting the script?
Unsubscribed chats stop sending events to the bot without a restart?

